how to get last url when press back from browser using javascript?
Assume I am on Stackoverflow and navigation to google
then I press back button from browser
I need to get last url using Javascript
I saw many code but they get the last Url Expect when using back button
How can I do That ?
any example code for This ?

That would be a privacy nightmare. It's none of your business which website I visited before or after yours.

I couldn't find any of the existing answers on SO that said anything other than "no, that's not possible" - some go into detail as to why it's not possible.   See : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=referrer+url+when+navigating+back

I do not believe this is possible between two separate websites like google and stackoverflow for the privacy reasons mentioned by Robby Cornelissen. But, within one website you wrote the code for knowing which URL was the most recent before the current should be doable with code that looks something like this:
// Store the current URL before navigating away
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('lastUrl', window.location.href);
});

// Retrieve the last URL when the page loads
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var lastUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('lastUrl');
    if (lastUrl) {
        console.log('Last URL:', lastUrl);
    }
});

